# understanding of struts1.x configuration file

Tags: struts

below is the code in struts config file

```
<action-mappings type="com.jpmc.invconfirm.presentation.struts.controllers.InvestorConfirmActionMapping">
    <action path="/getLoanDetail" 
            type="com.jpmc.invconfirm.base.presentation.struts.actions.StrutsIoCAction" 
            name="InvConfLoanDetailPageLoadForm" 
            parameter="GET_LOAN_DETAIL"  
            input="welcomePage" 
            validate="false"
            scope="request">
        <forward name="success" path="loandetail" />
        <forward name="failure" path="sysError" />
    </action>
</action-mappings>
```

My question is,

1. what the "type" attribute in   element will do.
2. what the "PARAMETER" attribute in  element will do.

Answer (score 0):

"type" refers to the classname of the Action.
"parameter" refers to the request parameter for the Action.

May I suggest finding a good book on the Struts framework?  There are several out there.

Comment: @Edmanet ..

in the above code they are using type attribute in two places

  1. inside<action-mappings> element and other one is inside 
     <action>element ...what is the difference of it??

Answer (score 0):

[http://www.amazon.com/Jakarta-Struts-Pocket-Reference-Cavaness/dp/0596005199](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005199)

http://struts.apache.org/1.x/userGuide/building_controller.html#actionmapping

Answer (score 0):

**type** element refers the action class name with package.

The request parameter name is specified using the **parameter** attribute. Here the request parameter name is GET_LOAN_DETAIL.
The request parameter name specified in the action handler is "GET_LOAN_DETAIL". So this should be specified as the property name for the submit button.